# Json Parsing Problem with Dotnet webserivces

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am posting some values to dotnet webservice.For this i am using AsiFormDataRequest.Values are posted suceesfully but coming response is in xml format. so iam not able to get the success or failure message in json format. 
   What i want to do for getting json response after posting to server.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: Depending on the server you need to add "Accept: application/json" to the header of your request. Sometimes this triggers that the response is in JSON instead of XML.

Comment: iam using httprequest Post method.Now getting json response but it always shows the message is "Failed" when giving correct values to their corresponding parameters.

Comment: You better show the Objective-C code for sending the request and receiving the answer. And please also show the full response that says "Failed". It'll help us help you. And what have you changed that you're now getting a different response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the server to respond with JSON instead of XML. There is nothing you can do about this from within your app. If you don't have control over the server then you need to forget JSON and parse the XML instead.

Comment: but this same webservice link called through android coding it gives json response but in iphone its not coming..

Comment: iam using httprequest Post method.Now getting json response but it always shows the message is "Failed" when giving correct values to their corresponding parameters.